# ¿Cual Es El Proceso De Instalación De Un Apk Y Sus Directorios?

Tags: android

He querido saber sobre los procesos que se llevan a cabo cuando un apk se instala y los archivos que contiene este donde se llevaran como que ese mismo archivo apk se guarda como una copia en data/app. Gracias.

Comment: revisa http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/the-installation-steps-of-android-package y http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442979/android-understanding-the-apk-installation-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tambien se crea una carpeta en /data/data/nombre_del _paquete
la cual contiene bases de datos o archivos de configuracion de la 
aplicacion, carpeta la cual puedes acceder si tienes privilegios de
super usuario(ROOT)